# Android retrofit2 connect timed out

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am facing a problem that i want send a GET request to linkit 7697.

It's work perfect when i request through chrome and postman.

Here are the snapshots from postman

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

I thought the request doesn't need any request headers or body, and response will be plain html text/html.

But i was failed and got below log

```
D/OkHttp: --> GET http://192.168.0.7/F http/1.1
D/OkHttp: --> END GET
D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

Below are my android code:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(logging).connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.7/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).
                    client(httpClient.build()).build();

    Call<ResponseBody> call = retrofit.create(LinkltApi.class).requestTurn();
    call.enqueue(callback);

@GET("/F")
Call<ResponseBody> requestTurn();
```

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: try increasing the connect timeout to 60 instead 10.

Comment: in screenshot you are requesting `/R` and in code it is `/F` so is it okay?

Comment: /R, /F are work in postman, just different API, but totally same

Comment: you are testing this on real device or emulator. use chrome of phone and request the same. see if its working

Comment: I use real device, and it's work on chrome of phone.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i fix it. 
I put the double "//". 
One is at the end of baseUrl(http://192.168.0.7/) 
and another is on the start of the (@GET("/F"))

Thanks everyone!